# Adding yuml diagrams into wiki pages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

Is it somehow possible to insert yuml (https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples) diagrams into vsts-wiki pages?

I've tried it using the image markdown syntax:

```
![image](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]->[Billing Address])
```

Or a more complex one:

```
![image](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]<>1->*[Order], [Customer]-[note: Aggregate Root{bg:cornsilk}])
```

But the wiki page doesn't render it, instead the markdown is shown in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yuml diagrams are supported for VSTS wiki page.

Just use the default [**yuml syntax**](https://github.com/jaime-olivares/vscode-yuml/wiki) , such as:

```
<img src="http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]->[Billing Address]" >
```

[image: uml preview]

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of using html tags in markdown. Perfect

Comment: Interesting. I use [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/) but it isn't supported. I'll have to consider YUML. Although, it looks equally troublesome to maintain.